# ag-grid checkboxSelection how to write cellRenderer that listens

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

How do I write a simple cell renderer in ag-grid react, that listens to the value of the checkbox if selected?

```
{
    field: "test",
    headerName: "Test",
    checkboxSelection: true,
    cellRenderer: TestCell,
},
```

For example, I want TestCell to render 1 if the row is selected, and 0 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [cellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/) property on a columnDef object to render a custom value for a particular cell.

The [rowSelected](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#reference-selection-rowSelected) event can be used to trigger an event when the selection is changed.

And use [redrawRows](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/view-refresh/#reference-refresh-redrawRows) to efficiently update the value of a cell.

##### Example:

```js
// Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/bvaaWLDOzA5mHbtc?open=index.jsx&preview

const columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'isChecked',
      headerCheckboxSelection: true,
      checkboxSelection: true,
      cellRenderer: (params) => {
        return params.node.selected ? "True" : "False"
      }
    },
    { field: 'sport' },
    { field: 'year', maxWidth: 120 },
  ]

... 

  const onRowSelected = useCallback((params) => params.api.redrawRows(params.node), [])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much, it was the callback that was missing on my code.  super helpful.